# Handling leap years in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, leap-year

I have a program where the user enters a date and then compares it to another date to see which one comes first.

How would I go about writing a code where the user inputs Feb 29 and the program returns Feb 28 instead (since there is no leap year)?

Example:

```
def date(prompt):
''' returns the date that user inputs and validates it'''  
while True:
    try:
        date = raw_input(prompt)
        if len(date) >= 5:
            month = date[0:2]
            day = date[3:5]
        dateObject = datetime.date(2011, int(month), int(day))
        return dateObject
    except ValueError:
            print "Please enter a valid month and day"
```

Comment: This sounds rather like homework to me. If so, please add the homework tag, and you are more likely to get answers that can help you.

Comment: In this context I would not return a different date but tell the user that the date doesn't exist and to try again. You can just use recursion for that.

Comment: @carpetsmoker I can do that but I wanted to get the program to just automatically input a date either mar 01 or feb 28th, if it's possible :)

Comment: Right, well, that's obvious ... Use the calender.isleap() mentioned in my answer ... **if calender.isleap(year) and month == 2 and day == 29: day = 28** ... Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

How do you compare dates? If you use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) functions then this should already account for this sort of stuff.

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28)
datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 29)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month

>>> datetime.datetime(1600, 2, 29)
datetime.datetime(1600, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```

`datetime.timedelta()` is used to represent the difference between two dates

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28) + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 10, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime(1600, 2, 28) + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
datetime.datetime(1600, 3, 9, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 28) - datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 10)
datetime.timedelta(-41)
```

Don't know how this fits in your code, but it may be an option ;-)

Comment: I don't think your code would fit into my coding, but thanks though!! :)

Comment: In that case you can use [calender.isleap()](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap) to check if the given year is a leap year ...

Answer (score 6):

If you are checking that: `month == 2 and day == 29` it is redundant to also check if it is a leap year with [calendar.isleap()](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap). A `date`/`datetime` would raise a `ValueError` if it was set to Feb 29th on a non-leapyear.